# package gentium-tug: cannot find font in map file(s)

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

Trying the new package gentium-tug with the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gentium}


\begin{document}
Olá
\end{document}
```

I get this

```
Cannot find font ec-gentiumplus-regular in map file(s).
```

My questions are:

1. Using tlmgr for installing the package shouldn't take care of updating the “map” files with the information about the new font?
2. Can I update the "map" files with

   updmap-sys --enable Map=gentium.map

(I'm not sure about the name of the map file)?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the map file is not included in the default map; this is an error that should be reported on the TeX Live mailing list: http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live

For the moment you should be able to do with either adding the map file manually with

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map gentium-type1.map
```

(or other methods to acquire super user privileges) or by adding the map file to your document with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gentium}
\pdfmapfile{+gentium-type1.map}

\begin{document}
Olá
\end{document}
```

You'll get warnings when later updates will solve the issue with the map file.